# drm-kmod-20220907_2 not supported for this configuration / NVIDIA : Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module

Tags: kernel, drivers, freebsd, compiling, nvidia

I need to conduct some tests on top of the FreeBSD 13.1.

So,I've installed it on one of my disks. I've installed xfce4 and KDE,Xorg and from the ports (after having upgraded them).

I've installed the nvidia-driver version. 535.146.02 and I didn't have any problem.

The problem arises when I tried to install the package drm-kmod from ports.

Unfortunately I'm not able to compile it.

This is what happened :

```
root@marietto:/usr/ports/graphics/drm-kmod # make
====> drm-kmod-20220907_2 not supported for this configuration.
```

ok. At this point I tried to install it from the packages :

```
root@marietto:/usr/ports/graphics/drm-kmod # make clean
====> cleaning for drm-kmod-20220907_2
```

so :

```
root@marietto:/usr/ports/graphics/drm-kmod # pkg install drm-kmod

New packages to be INSTALLED : drm-kmod: 20220907_2 
OK

nano /home/marietto/.xinitrc :

exec ck-launch-session dbus-launch --exit-with-session startxfce4

nano /etc/rc.conf :

kdm5_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"
hald_enable="YES"
kld_list="nvidia nvidia-modeset"
rpcbind_enable="YES"
dtcms_enable="YES"
inetd_enable="YES"

nano /boot/loader.conf

vmm_load="YES"
nmdm_load="YES"
tmpfs_load="YES"
cryptodev_load="YES"
zfs_load="YES"
kern.racct.enable="1"
kern.vty=vt kern.cam.scsi_delay="10000"

nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section        "Device"
Identifier      "Card0"
Driver         "nvidia"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

root@marietto:/home/marietto # lspci

01:00.0 NVIDIA GP106
01:00.1 NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio Controller
02:00.0 NVIDIA TU102
02:00.1 NVIDIA TU102 High Definition Audio Controller
02:00.2 NVIDIA TU102 USB Controller
02:00.3 NVIDIA TU102 Serial BUS Controller
```

Now,I want to startx to start xfce4 :

```
marietto@marietto: $ startx

Fatal server error : no screens found (EE) 
Check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"

nano /var/log/Xorg.0.log :

NVIDIA dlloader X driver 535.146.02
NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA gpus NVIDIA
Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module
```

What to do ?

Answer (score 1):

### NVIDIA and DRM

NVIDIA has its own DRM module as the NVIDA Unified Driver was built for FreeBSD and Linux systems using Kernel Object files.  The `.ko` file "attaches" itself to the running/booted kernel.  Since this driver is the proprietary NVIDIA blob it's known to have issues with Wayland.

### Install

1. `pkg remove drm-kmod`
2. `pkg install nvidia-drm-kmod`

### Configure

1. `# sysrc -f /etc/rc.conf kld_list+=nvidia-drm`